# Does OOTB SharePoint Wiki meet these requirements?

Tags: wiki

If not, how elaborate/difficult are the customization's (possibly add-ons) to meet these requirements (and to what expend do these customization's complicate future upgrades to newer SharePoint versions)?

Our department is planning to set up a wiki to improve knowledge management to:

- Make product knowledge more accessible to all (new) employees.
- Document several procedures (e.g. ERP work instructions, PLM work instruction, …)

Regarding the wiki platform:

- Some employees have good experiences with MediaWiki and would prefer to use that platform.
- SharePoint is also on the table, because SharePoint is about to be rolled out company wide for managing office documents. No experience with this wiki is present in the company.

Our goal with knowledge management was described, more elegantly than I could, in a certain post on the web as follows:

> The advantage of a good wiki is how well it enables the process change
>   from Develop-Share-Repeat to Collaborate.

Followed by, what, if true, is possibly is our main concern for using SharePoint as wiki platform.

> SharePoint is not really a collaboration platform even the "wiki" is
>   really just a way to share/not share html files and has shorthand for
>   links to other files.

Our requirements for the wiki platform are:

1. The platform should enable that the wiki can be mainly managed by (key) users (IT capacity is limited in our company)
   =>Use the system OOTB no (or very limited) configuration needed.
2. Sufficient flexibility so the wiki can grow somewhat organically
   => Good taxonomy (e.g. category tree,) is important.
   We aim for a flat “file structure” and use categories / tags to create structure.
3. Intuitive user interface and wiki page editor (copy past from word is also nice to).
4. Reuse of content of other pages should be possible. (e.g. display the content from a sub-procedure step in several main procedures and once the sub procedure step updated, all pages that have it embedded content will be updated appropriately.)
5. Good searching possibilities.
6. Easily visualize references between pages (e.g.  “Transcluded templates” and “Page transcluded on”)
7. Printing and exporting to PFD possible

Comment: The SharePoint wikis are trash, if people already have used Mediawiki, they will not come around to use something as inferior to what SharePoint offers. Your best bet would be to use something like OneNote.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.
Is your bad experience based on the latest version of share point or on an older version?
One could hope that the functionality has improved the last versions.

Comment: I've used wikis from 2007, 2010, and 2013. There has been no investment in making these any better since implementation in 2007. That should tell you something.

Answer (score 0):

We are facing a similar situation; searching the net I found comparison between OOTB SharePoint wiki and a commercial add-on.
If you can believe this comparison, the OOTB functionality, you require, is rather limited…

http://www.kwizcom.com/sharepoint-add-ons/sharepoint-wiki-plus/overview/

Comment: (1) "Taxonomy management - Hierarchical categories and Web 2.0-style tagging and tag cloud/index" ==>Partially in SharePoint 2010/2013/2016

(2) Easily copy fully-styled office documents (including tables, formatting and images) => not present

Wiki content templates
 
Reference Manager
 X
Table of contents (automatically generated)
 X
Export to MS WORD and PDF
 X
Wiki Page printing
 X
Wiki page-level discussions
 X
Cross-browser support: IE, Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome
 Limited support for IE and Firefox